# How can I vectorize logical operator on multiple columns of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, logical-operators

I am trying to apply the logical `or` operator on multiple boolean columns of a dataframe, but I do not know in advance these columns. I resorted to use apply (see example below), but I would like to vectorize this operation.

example:

```
df =
    A       B      C
0   True    False  False
1   False   False  True
2   False   False  False

list_columns = df.columns
```

Using apply :

```
df[list_columns].apply(lambda row: any(row), axis=1)
```

Any ideas how to vectorize this?

Comment: `df[list_columns].any(1)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [369]: df[list_columns].any(axis=1)
Out[369]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Am guessing it is - this resembles output with OP's solution too.